# After Alter Rename to with table, we cant create the table with old name

Tags: cockroachdb

Unable to create table with old name after using Alter Rename to (renamed table)

`Alter table testdb rename to testdb2`

now not able to create table with testdb

`Cockroach Db Version: 19.1.2`

Comment: is there any error message?

Comment: it just saying, table already exists but the old table name not showing in the tables list

Answer (score 1):

Cockroach does not currently support atomically swapping table names. See this issue: https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/54562

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on v19.1.2 as well as several later versions, and it looks to be working fine:

```
> create table testdb (a int);
CREATE TABLE

> alter table testdb rename to testdb2;
RENAME TABLE

> create table testdb (a int);
CREATE TABLE
```

Can you share the commands you are running? There is a known limitation about this within the context of a single, multi-statement transaction, but I'm not clear if you're doing that: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/known-limitations.html#schema-changes-within-transactions

Also, v19.1.2 is quite old and is no longer supported. You should upgrade to at least 19.2: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/releases/release-support-policy.html#current-supported-releases

Comment: some way it locked with a cache or reference to table name by the db. when we trying to create table it complaining table already exists, if we perform any other operations it saying table not exists.

Comment: Can you say more about how you're performing these operations? Are you using an ORM or doing it directly in the SQL shell?